# Dúvida sobre 'NUMA'(non uniform memory access) em Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Alguém me pode ajudar a compreender em português o conceito de 'NUMA' e as suas respectivas caracterísitcas sff?

Já encontrei sites em inglês etc, mas continuo sem perceber!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse conceito não é um conceito do SQL Server, ou do MySQL, na verdade é um conceito que vem arquitetura do Hardware e o banco de dados precisa ter recursos para suportar (ou aproveitar melhor) esses recursos de hardware.

Esse conceito vem de uma tendência que o nosso hardware atual tem de ter mais de um processador, como consequencia você vai perceber que cada processador tem seu barramento de comunicação, inclusive com a memória, sendo assim, eles recebem seus proprios canais de comunicação (I/O) e sua propria porção de memória (chamamos isso de numa-node (ou nó).

Os processadores de diferentes nós podem acessar a memória dos outros nós, mas, logicamente com tempos e formas diferentes, o que leva a um **acesso não uniforme de memória**.

Quando você executa uma Query, o SQL Server precisa alocar memória para execução, então, ele usa um conjunto de mecanismos para garantir que tem a porção de memória adequada para a query e se não tiver, ele coloca ela em uma fila, que varia de acordo com o tamanho da memória requerida (se não me engano).

Existe um contador no Memory Manager Object que lhe diz a quantidade de queries que estão esperando por memória, se você estiver com problema de falta de memória, o contador estará com um valor alto, o bom mesmo é zero :)

Sendo assim, na verdade, dependendo do hardware que você tem, você acaba tendo que entender um pouco da arquitetura disponível para ajustar a performance do servidor de banco de dados, seja modificando hardware ou configurações no server.

Boa parte desses indicadores, inclusive a alocação de memória por NUMA-node pode ser analisada via Query (vide SQL Internals) e versões do SQL Server superiores ao 2008 possuem melhorias explicitas com base no numero de nós disponível em hardware.(SQL Server Internals).

Material sobre isso em Pt-br é dificil, mas, esse link te da uma visão bem básica dos recursos e esclarece os conceitos básicos da arquitetura e do que o SQL usa:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178144.aspx

Para entender melhor, ou para ir mais a fundo em como o comportamento do acesso a memória pode ser otimizado, veja:

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Server-Internals-Dmitri-Korotkevitch/dp/1430259620/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1432705945&sr=1-3&keywords=sql+internals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430259620)

Achei um otimo material sobre Linux + MySQL que cobre os conceitos:
http://blog.jcole.us/2010/09/28/mysql-swap-insanity-and-the-numa-architecture/

Comment: Muito obrigado @Intruso !